# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer]

Tags: spring-mvc

ayuda al siguiente problema. presento el siguiente mensaje al ingresar un nuevo elemento a mi tabla de registro. Whitelabel Error Page

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Thu Jan 06 12:23:21 COT 2022
> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

en el panel del spring presenta el siguiente mensaje :

> [2m2022-01-06 11:26:58.510[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16208[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9078-exec-3][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'idat.edu.pe.daa2.Ayl.entidades.CiudadEntity'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '"lima"'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""lima""]

Esto sucede cuando ingreso un dato en texto "LIMA", sin embargo, cuando ingreso un numero entero si registra sin problemas y lo verifico en la tabla Mysql.

Ayuda por favor con este problema.

[imagen 1[[image: imagen 2imagen 2]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: No olvides que el código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden visualizar las imágenes.